# Hacer consultas a base de datos desde un evento click en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

estoy trabajando en mi primer sitio web conectado a una base de datos utilizando mongodb, nodejs y javascript. Mi consulta es sobre cómo puedo hacer una consulta a mi base de datos desde un evento click de mi botón. Se que puedo usar la función find() para la consulta y pasar datos dinámicos a un documento html a través de un motor de vistas y un enrutador que reciba peticiones, pero lo que quiero hacer es que la consulta la dispare un evento click y cargue la información de la base de datos en la misma pagina sin abandonar la ruta actual en la que me encuentro.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. En todo caso lo que pides es simplemente realizar una llamada Ajax y mostrar el resultado de la misma. Existen muchos ejemplos en la Red. ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? La idea del sitio es que plantees una duda específica, mostrando un [mre] y explicando en qué parte tienes problemas. Saludos

Comment: La pregunta es muy abierta y nos podemos imaginar mil escenarios... pero así por encima, podrías hacer una peticion ajax (por ejemplo con fecth) al servidor, para que te retornara el resultado... y ya con el lo pintas como quieras en la página.